# Burninate [php-date]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, burninate-request

I believe that [php-date](/questions/tagged/php-date) should be burninated.

It serves **no purpose** as these questions are *usually* tagged with [php](/questions/tagged/php) and some date-time tag.

[image: Calling Trogdor]

Comment: @animuson Thanks ^_^ I **knew** I served a _purpose_!

Comment: [tag:burninate-request] doesn't actually imply [tag:stackoverflow] ;)

Comment: @minitech all of the requests here **do** imply it :-P

Comment: Yeah, burninate it. And all php datetime questions with it. It's a sad and ugly pile of dupes. Easier to have a clean start than to find relevant things in there.

Comment: @Gordon I hear ya. It's unlikely to ever happen, but it would indeed be the best way to go. I'm sometimes thinking, maybe a bunch of top people from the PHP tag should simply start writing PHP tutorials (like, one on the issue of how to convert dates) and publish them on a site of their own. With peer reviews, top quality, and constant editing, but with a very limited circle of professional editors. The resulting traffic *must* be enough to make a living or at least cover the costs.... then everyone could just point there when the 99,999th garbage duplicate PHP question pops up

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA sorry, didn't notice that you'd rolled back that Stack Overflow tag previously!  Although it has been added independently by three people and the question *is* Stack Overflow specific (though I get your point about all the burnination requests being SO specific).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can't see a situation where someone would be asking about [php-date](/questions/tagged/php-date) and not talking about [php](/questions/tagged/php). Other language agnostic tags sufficiently describe date/time related questions.

It's been burninated and is now synonymous with [php](/questions/tagged/php) to keep it from coming back.

[image: Burninated!]